# onPremisesDomainName for AAD group object?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Do AAD Group objects have **onPremisesDomainName** property, similar to that in User objects. I did not find it in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Just wondering why there isn't a parity with User objects.

Answer (score 1):

The onPremisesDomainName contains the on-premises domainFQDN, also called dnsDomainName synchronized from the on-premises directory.The property is only populated for customers who are synchronizing their on-premises directory to Azure Active Directory via Azure AD Connect.

The domainFQDN and DnsDomainName have been added for Group objects as of version 1.1.553.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-version-history

There are a number of similar threads worth checking out. 
[Find Domain Name in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270069/find-domain-name-in-active-directory)
[Get domain\username from microsoft graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429980/get-domain-username-from-microsoft-graph?rq=1)

Comment: I tried to query onPremisesDomainName using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,displayName,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,onPremisesDomainName but did not seem to be able to obtain any value for the domain.